# Relationship to find ancestor in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a tree of one-to-many relationships that looks like this:

> organization -> operation -> region -> area -> site

The `organization` is the top level ancestor. A `site` has an `area_id`, `area` has a `region_id`, and so on up the tree.

For each entity under organization, I'd like to be able to quickly access the organization ancestor through a relationship like `site.organization`, `area.organization`, etc.

What would the `relationship` on each entity look like to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to use a [composite "secondary" join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins) for those classes that do not have a direct relationship with organization. For example site:

```
class Site(Base):

    organization = relationship(
        "Organization",
        secondary="join(Operation, Region).join(Area)",
        uselist=False,
        innerjoin=True,
        viewonly=True)
```

while region should just use the table operation as a secondary:

```
class Region(Base):

    organization = relationship(
        "Organization",
        secondary="operation",
        uselist=False,
        innerjoin=True,
        viewonly=True)
```

The above is a reduced version displaying only the relationship configurations. A concrete example follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.bind = engine

Session = sessionmaker()

class Organization(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'organization'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Operation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'operation'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    organization_id = Column(ForeignKey('organization.id'))
    organization = relationship("Organization")

class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'region'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    operation_id = Column(ForeignKey('operation.id'))
    organization = relationship(
        "Organization",
        secondary="operation",
        uselist=False, innerjoin=True, viewonly=True)
    operation = relationship("Operation")

class Area(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'area'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    region_id = Column(ForeignKey('region.id'))
    organization = relationship(
        "Organization",
        secondary="join(Operation, Region)",
        uselist=False, innerjoin=True, viewonly=True)
    region = relationship("Region")

class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'site'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    area_id = Column(ForeignKey('area.id'))
    organization = relationship(
        "Organization",
        secondary="join(Operation, Region).join(Area)",
        uselist=False, innerjoin=True, viewonly=True)
    area = relationship("Area")

Base.metadata.create_all()

session = Session()
session.add(Site(area=Area(region=Region(operation=Operation(organization=Organization())))))
session.commit()

site = session.query(Site).options(joinedload(Site.organization)).first()
print(site)
print(site.organization)
print(site.area.organization)
print(site.area.region.organization)
print(site.area.region.operation.organization)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work and the linked documentation is confusing... the example shown has a foreign key to the top-level entity on each sub-entity. In my case I only have a foreign key for the immediate parent in each entity.

Comment: What can I say, it works for me. If you'd provide actual example code in the question itself it'd be easier to produce answers that work out of the box. Without your code the examples in this answer are bound to require some fine tuning. The general idea is: create a derived table / composite as the secondary, mainly the required joins. Since what you're after is a many-to-one, but a secondary is required, you have to pass `uselist=False` in order to produce a scalar relationship. If your foreign keys are not nullable, pass `innerjoin=True` as well.